# Iterative Calculation in R

Tags: r

Let's say we have some variables:

```
s = 95
k = 100
r = .05
g = sx * .1
sx = s - px
px = need to solve for this
```

How would you set up r to solve this? In Excel, you can make a target cell, let's call it `y` to zero via Goal Seek or Solver.. and this involves an iterative calculation.

```
y = px - s/k-1 * r - g
```

Excel would calculate px by reducing y to zero.

Here `px = 9.45945`

How would r handle this?

Comment: You could try `optim`

Comment: I have no idea how to make it actually do what I need it to do - can't figure out how to set that up. (well I tried optimize, not optim, maybe that's the problem?)

Comment: @dwdionis Something is missing here. Can you revise your post? Is the equation for `y` derived based on a condition you did not provide?

Comment: Are you sure that `y = px - s/k-1 * r - g` ? Or is it `y = px - s/(k-1) * r - g` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let us clarify that the question is asking to solve a system of three variables in three unknowns.  That is:

```
Solve this system of 3 equations in the 3 unknowns px, sx and g:

       0.1 * sx      - g  = 0 
 px +        sx           = s 
 px                  - g  = s/k-1 * r

where s, k and r are known constants given in the question and we have 
rearranged the equations to put the constant terms on the right hand
side and have vertically aligned the variables on the left hand side.
```

This system of equations is actually easy to solve by hand (eliminate sx by replacing sx in the first equation with s - px and then subtract the two remaining equations to eliminate g.  Finally we are left with one equation in one unknown which is readily solved).  Since the objective here is to use R we instead show several different ways to use R.

**1) linear algebra**  Since these are linear equations we can formulate it as a matrix problem and solve it.  The matrix `m` is formed from the coefficients of the equations above.  The first column of `m` is the coefficients of `px`, the next column is the coefficients of `sx` and the final column is the coefficients of `g`.  For example, the coefficients of `px` are 0, 1, and 1 in the three equations respectively. The right hand side vector is `rhs` and `solve` can be used to conceptually invert `m` and multiply it by `rhs`.

No packages are used, no explicit iterative calculation is involved and no manual substitution of one formula into another is required.  We deal with the three equations as is and let the computer solve them.

```
s <- 95; k <- 100; r <- .05
m <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1,   0.1, 1, 0,   -1, 0, -1), 3)
rhs <- c(0, s, s/k-1 * r)

solve(m, rhs)
## [1]  9.454545 85.545455  8.554545
```

The value in the above output vector are the values of `px`, `sx` and `g`.

**2) fixed point iteration** If we have an estimate of `px` then from 
the second equation we could get an estimate of `sx` and using that from 
the first equation we could get an estimate of `g` and from that we could 
get a new estimate of `px` using the third equation.  Writing that as the function `f` we start off with an initial estimate of 1 and then iterate it until the values converge. No packages are used.

```
f <- function(px) {
  sx <- s - px
  g <- .1 * sx
  s/k-1 * r + g 
}

px <- 1
for(i in 1:50) {
  prev <- px
  px <- f(px)
  cat(i, px, "\n")
  if (abs(px - prev) < 1e-5) break
}

## 1 10.3 
## 2 9.37 
## 3 9.463 
## 4 9.4537 
## 5 9.45463 
## 6 9.454537 
## 7 9.454546
```

**2a) optimize** We could alternately use `optimize` (in the base of R) to minimize the distance between `f(x)` and `x` given bounds for `px`:

```
optimize(function(px) (f(px) - px)^2, c(0, 100))
## $minimum
## [1] 9.454545
##
## $objective
## [1] 3.155444e-30
```

**2b) uniroot** or use `uniroot` (also base R) to find the root of f(px) - px:

```
uniroot(function(px) f(px) - px, c(0, 100))
## $root
## [1] 9.454545
## 
## $f.root
## [1] 0
##
## $iter
## [1] 1
##
## $init.it
## [1] NA
##
## $estim.prec
## [1] 90.54545
```

**3) Ryacas**   Below we set this up using the Ryacas package which allows direct symbolic specification of the three equations.

```
# devtools::install_github("mikldk/ryacas0")

library(Ryacas0)

s <- 95
k <- 100
r <- .05

sx <- Sym("sx")
px <- Sym("px")
g <- Sym("g")

res <- Solve(List(g == sx * 0.1, sx == s - px, px - s/k-1 * r - g == 0), 
   List(px, sx, g))
```

giving:

```
res
## Yacas matrix:
##      [,1]            [,2]           [,3]        
## [1,] px == 1.05/0.11 sx == 9.4/0.11 g == 9.4/1.1
```

The above are exact values as symbolic expressions but we can evaluate them to get floating point approximations like this:

```
Eval(res)
## "( px == 9.54545454545454 )" "( sx == 85.4545454545455 )" "( g == 8.54545454545454 )"
```

Comment: G.Grothendieck - I can't seem to get this  code: 

optimize(function(px) (f(px) - px)^2, c(0, 100))

to work properly. Is that correct? Maybe my other code before it is not correct? How did you set up the function?

Comment: Define the three constants and `f` and then run the optimize statement    Here is all the code again. Copy it and paste it into a fresh R session. `s <- 95; k <- 100; r <- .05; 
f <- function(px) {
  sx <- s - px;
  g <- .1 * sx;
  s/k-1 * r + g 
};
optimize(function(px) (f(px) - px)^2, c(0, 100))`

Comment: I got it to work, thanks.

I'm confused as to how you formatted your "optimize" function code. 

optimize(f, interval ...)    ...... this is all you set, right? f = function, and then you set an interval with c(0,100) ? 

I'm quite confused how "r" can understand this "function(px) (f(px) - px)^2" 

First you chose the function "px" , and you assign it to "f", but how "r" reads (f(px) - px) makes no sense to me at all" 

If "f" here the "f" variable? If so, what exactly is "(f(px) - px)" ?

Comment: `px` is not a function.  It is the formal argument to the anonymous function that is passed to `optimize` . The anonymous function passed to `optimize`  is `function(px) { (f(px) - px)^2 }` where the `f` in its body is as defined.

Comment: Hey again - I'm still having trouble with this thing ... here's some more code:

put <- function(px) { 

mgta <- 0.01
volT_a <- .17
s <- 500
k <- 600
r <- .05
NAV <- s - px
d1a <- NAV/k-1 + (r - mgt_a) + 5 * volT_a
d2a <- NAV/k-1 - (r - mgt_a) + 5 * volT_a
px <-  (NAV * d1a - k * d2a)



}

print(optimize(function(px) (put(px) - px)^2, c(0, 0.0000000000000001)))

I'm trying to calculate value of px. 

It should be 263.882353. 

How do I rearrange the optimize function to do this? Your help has been great!

Answer (score 3):

After some algebra, the solution in closed form of `px - s/k-1 * r - g == 0` is

```
px <- (10*k*r + 10*s + k*s)/(11*k)
# [1] 9.545455
```

A solution using the `nleqslv` package:

```
library(nleqslv)

fn <- function(px) {
  s <- 95
  k <- 100
  r <- .05
  sx <- s - px
  g <- sx * .1
  y <- px - s/k-1 * r - g
  return(y)
}

nleqslv(1, fn)

# $x
# [1] 9.545455
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution that should work as long as it is something that can be resolved to linear equation.

```r
s = 95
k = 100
r = .05

g = function(sx) {
    sx * 0.1
}

sx = function(px) {
    s - px
}

fn = function(px) {
    px - s/k - 1 * r - g(sx(px))
}

foo = function(fn) {
    x1 = 1
    x2 = 2
    y1 = fn(x1)
    y2 = fn(x2)
    m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)  # Line slope
    solve(-m, -m * x1 + y1)
}

foo(fn)
#> [1] 9.545455
```